# WebPart Properties

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property, web-part-property

I would like to manage my WebPart Properties.

I would store an ID -> this id is the id of a configuration for my webpart.

First: How can i Store it?

Second: How can i Find it?

I'm using the `renderOption()`, the `displayEditMode()`, `displayDesignMode()`.

Answer (score 1):

This article from Microsoft describes exactly how to use web part properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx

Basically, you mark (decorate) a c# Property in your code as follow:

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("MyCategory")]
[WebDisplayName("Display Name")]
[WebDescription("My Description")]

public string MyProperty { set; get; }
```

Next up, you can access the property directly in your code:

```
string propertyValue = this.MyProperty;
```